# HttpWebRequest is throwing exception for 404

Tags: asp.net

I've found that HttpWebRequest is throwing WebException for not existing resources.
It seems to me very strange as HttpWebResponse has StatusCode property (NotFount item exist).
Do you think it has any reasons for that or maybe it is just developers issue?

```
var req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(someUrl);
using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse()) {
    if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK) { ...}
}
```

Comment: the API you're calling needs to return the correct error codes in the HTTP response. sounds like a developer issue to me, they are probably not catching the error properly.

Answer (score 3):

This is really a frustrating problem, which can be worked around by using the following extension method class and calling request.BetterGetResponse()

```
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------
//
//     Copyright (c) 2011 Garrett Serack. All rights reserved.
//
//
//     The software is licensed under the Apache 2.0 License (the "License")
//     You may not use the software except in compliance with the License.
//
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace CoApp.Toolkit.Extensions {
    using System;
    using System.Net;

    public static class WebRequestExtensions {
        public static WebResponse BetterEndGetResponse(this WebRequest request, IAsyncResult asyncResult) {
            try {
                return request.EndGetResponse(asyncResult);
            }
            catch (WebException wex) {
                if( wex.Response != null ) {
                    return wex.Response;
                }
                throw;
            }
        }

        public static WebResponse BetterGetResponse(this WebRequest request) {
            try {
                return request.GetResponse();
            }
            catch (WebException wex) {
                if( wex.Response != null ) {
                    return wex.Response;
                }
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You read more about it in my blog post on this subject at http://fearthecowboy.com/2011/09/02/fixing-webrequests-desire-to-throw-exceptions-instead-of-returning-status/

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(someUrl);
req.Method = "Head";

using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse()) {
    if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK) { ...}
}
```

[WebRequest and System.Net.WebException on 404, slow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/753877/webrequest-and-system-net-webexception-on-404-slow)