# Passing boolean value through HttpResponse

Tags: http, asp.net-web-api, httpresponse

What is the most appropriate (and elegant?) way to pass boolean value of true or false through HttpResponse. I need it for a GetCustomerExist method (using ASP.NET Web API). Am writing it to the body of the message, but feel it's not the wright way of doing it. Can I pass it in the response header somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of creating a method that checks for the existence of a customer, a more "RESTful" way would be to send a `HEAD` request to the customer resource. If the customer doesn't exist, answer with `404 Not Found` else with `200 OK`. In a `HEAD` request, you don't have to provide the message body.

In a quick sample, I was able to implement this in WebAPI like this. In the sample, odd ids do exist, even ones return a 404. Also, I add a fantasy header value to the response:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Head(int id)
{
    HttpResponseMessage msg;
    if (id % 2 == 0)
        msg = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
    else
        msg = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    msg.Headers.Add("Hello", "World");
    return msg;
}
```

Comment: Do you have any link with exemplary implementation? Am struggling to make it work. Found this: http://www.strathweb.com/2013/03/adding-http-head-support-to-asp-net-web-api/ but when oldContent is assigned it runs into an error

Comment: @Bartosz: I've checked this in a small sample and added the relevant lines to the answer.

Comment: thanks for your help. How does the code on the other side looks like though? When I execute HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse(); I get an exeption "The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found." Could base the logic on the exception but its not recommended as far as I'm aware

Comment: @Bartosz: good to know that it helped. Unforunately I don't know a way other than catching the WebException and inspecting the StatusCode. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1949610/how-can-i-catch-a-404 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3771065/httpwebrequest-is-throwing-exception-for-404 (the latter provides an extension method so at least the code is a bit cleaner though the try-catch remains).